# Lightweight AJAX objects recommendations?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm building a custom widget and i'm not supposed to use any framework such as jQuery, i need a lightweight cross browser object that supports POST & GET with callback, i've seen some solutions online but they include a lot of useless stuffs.

Thanks

Comment: What are you considering useless, it may help to explain why these can be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `XMLHttpRequest` object yourself.

I tend to like looking at the Mozilla site to see examples, and they have a nice explanation on this subject.

[Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

It isn't hard to do, and it supports any HTTP request, and is as simple or complicated as you want to make it, depending on how easy you want to make it to use.

jQuery has a nice API though, so copying their style may be useful.

**UPDATE:**

You should reference the link above, but to see how POST can be done, mainly you put the parameters into the `send` function you can look at this.  Don't just copy this code, I put it here for just a simple example.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
xhr.send(formData);
```

For GET you just put them in the URL, as you would in your address bar, and a null in the `send`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use JQuery, you can write one from scratch without using any library:-

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("yourdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

// change "GET" to "POST" if you want to POST 
xmlhttp.open("GET","/yourlink",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You may want to show code for POST also, but I thought he may want to learn about the parts to understand what types of values for readyState can be, for example.

Comment: @James Black: aside from the readyState (4 == Complete) the others are not guaranteed to trigger.

Comment: @mhitza - My point is that just posting the code with no context will help him to understand what is truly going on, or how to make it work as he wants.

Comment: I added a little comment about POST, as the parameters are placed in the send function.